# Perl regular expression to grep for a word after specific pattern

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I have the below line assigned to a variable:

```
"[ some contents ] NAME:saranyya"
```

How can I `grep` for a word that follows after this pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple capture might suit your needs. Though it is fairly unclear what you mean.

```
my ($word) = $string =~ /\Q[ some contents ] NAME:saranyya \E(.+)/;
```

The `\Q .. \E` escape will allow the use of the meta characters `[]` inside your regex. Any text following your pattern will be captured and assigned to `$word`.